# Query Cache Type Appears ON/not in X-cart App

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, x-cart

I have created a "my.cnf" in the /etc directly of my hosting server that is a VPS on GoDaddy.  The settings are enabling query_cache_type=1 and I increased the query_cache_size to 256 Mb.  I have rebooted the server and when I look at the global variables for this database using phpMyAdmin, they are set to the correct values.  I also query the variables and they are set correctly.  I am hosting X-cart 5 on this server and when the Xcart Admin runs system tools->Environment, I get that an error that says it is not setup correctly.  I have also provided an SSH connection to the X-cart support team and when they examine these two settings, they are getting query_cache_type=OFF and another default value for query_cache_size that is 1 Mb.  Does anyone know if there are permission settings or some other issues that do not let the application see these settings correctly in MySQL?  The SSH connection from the support team also cannot see that these are set correctly?

[image: Error message from Xcart Admin panel]

[image: phpMyAdmin showing the SQL settings on VPS]

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Problem solved!  This was a problem with moving to a dedicated VPS and the migration not being performed completely.  The SQL settings were OK but the DNS was never changed to point the new server IP.  Life is good!